# how to upload multimedia files into azure from android application

Tags: java, android, azure

Is there any way i can upload multimedia files such as audio from my voice recorder OR photo from my camera function from my android application into Microsoft Azure?

I looked at all the tutorial given such as server and client side and inserted the code into my project. But how exactly do i upload them through a "send" button on the application?

Please advice. Below is my codes for my basic camera application

```
package com.example.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity{

ImageView iv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.camera);


iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if(requestCode == 0)
{
    Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
}
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows Azure storage account, you could create a blob container and then upload your media files into blobs stored into the container. Your application would control the access clients have to these files using shared access strings or stored access policy.  For example, the following code runs as a Java console application and uploads a local .jpg file, along with some explanatory metadata, to a blob in the cloud.

```
public class SASmeta 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException, StorageException, IOException 
   {                        
   URI baseuri = new URI("http://grassy.blob.core.windows.net");
   CloudBlobClient blobclient = new CloudBlobClient(baseuri);
   MyUploadBlob("container1","sr=c&sv=2012-02-12&sig=b%2BK%2FmX8r7dLCVxs5PSPmmji1L6kSxNupp9SKF7yj27w%3D&si=r",blobclient);          
   }

public static void MyUploadBlob(String containerName, String containerSAS, CloudBlobClient blobClient) throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {    
   String blobName = "image1.jpg";  
   String localFileName = "c:\\myimages\\image1.jpg";  
   URI uri = new URI(blobClient.getEndpoint().toString() + "/" + containerName + "/" + blobName + "?" + containerSAS);
   CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, blobClient);    
   HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();    
   user.put("firstname", "Joe");
   user.put("lastname", "Smith" );
   user.put("age", "28");
   user.put("presenter", "no");  
   sasBlob.setMetadata(user);
   File fileReference = new File(localFileName);
   sasBlob.upload(new FileInputStream(fileReference), fileReference.length());
   System.out.println("The blob: " + blobName + " has been uploaded to:");
   System.out.println(uri);
   }
}
```

Comment: how does this work with a "send" button? Honestly, I'm quite confuse at the codes on how to upload multimedia files from my android application to the blob storage in my mobile services.